# How can I specify which package to pull from when using Config::get()?

Tags: laravel, configuration-files

I have created a Class for Tags, which has a method called getTypes() that looks like this:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Name\EnterpriseEntity\Traits\TagTraits;

class Tag extends EnterpriseModel
{
    protected $table = 'tags';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'owner', 'types', 'owner_type'];
    protected $types;
    use SoftDeletes;

    public function getTypes($type = NULL) 
    {
       if ($type != NULL) {
           $type = Config::get('enterpriseEntity::enterpriseEntityTag.types.'.$type, '');
       }else {
           $type = Config::get('enterpriseEntity::enterpriseEntityTag.types', []);
       }
       return $type;
    }
}
```

I have two things that I want to have a ManyToMany relationship with tags, Agents, which are in the same package as tags, and then Contacts which are in a different package.

The issue I have is when I try to run Tag->getTypes() from the ContactsController, Config::get() returns null.  When ran from the AgentsController, I get the array I am looking for.  I'm wondering how I should be specifying the package for Config::get to look in.

```php
Config::get('enterpriseEntity::enterpriseEntityTag.types', []);
Config::get('EnterpriseEntity::enterpriseEntityTag.types', []);
```

But neither worked and I'm not sure what else to try or if it is even possible.

Comment: Why not publish your assets/config files and then just call them like `config('enterpriseEntityTag.types', [])`?